# Custom ORDER BY Explanation

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I found this some time ago and have been using it since; however, looking at it today, I realized that I do not fully understand why it works.  Can someone shed some light on it for me?

```
ORDER BY  s.type!= 'Nails',
          s.type!= 'Bolts',
          s.type!= 'Washers',
          s.type!= 'Screws',
          s.type!= 'Staples',
          s.type!= 'Nuts', ...
```

If I order by s.type, it orders alphabetically.  If I use the example above it uses the same order as the line positions.  What I don't understand is the use of !=.  If I use = it appears in the opposite order.  I cannot wrap my head around the concept of this.

It would reason to me that using = in place of the !='s above would place Nails first in position, but it does not, it place it in the last.  I guess my question is this: Why do i have to use !=, not = in this situation?

Comment: So, if I don't understand something, even though I like the elegance and simplicity of a solution, I should hold my hands over my ears and repeat "La, la, la".  I don't like this approach; I would rather learn something new and become comfortable with it.

Comment: wow, neat hack! :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I've never seen it but it seems to make sense.

At first it orders by `s.type != 'Nails'`. This is `false` for every row that contains `Nails` in the `type` column. After that it is sorted by `Bolts`. Again for all columns that do contain `Bolts` as a `type` this evaluates to false. And so on.

A small test reveals that `false` is ordered before `true`. So you have the following: First you get all rows with `Nails` on top because the according `ORDER BY` evaluated to `false`  and `false` comes first. The remaining rows are sorted by the second `ORDER BY` criterion. And so on.

```
 type     | != Nails | != Bolts | != Washers
'Nails'   | false    | true     | true
'Bolts'   | true     | false    | true
'Washers' | true     | true     | false
```

Comment: This is purely a thought.  But I'd assume that it orders false before true, because of their respected integer values of 0 and 1 where 0 (false) comes before 1 (true).

Comment: It worked amazingly for me across every SQL server I threw it at (PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite)!!

Answer (score 92):

[@Scott Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287611/scott-bailey) suggested great idea. But it can be even simpler (you don't have to create custom function) since PostgreSQL 9.5. Just use [`array_position`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html) function:

```
ORDER BY array_position(array['Nails','Bolts','Washers','Screws','Staples','Nuts'], s.type)
```

Comment: tried it on my dev instance, was great, production still on 9.3 .. not so great

Comment: This applies to columns of type `Text`, I tried this with a column type `character` and the function threw an error - hopefully this helps :)

Comment: A similar question that will also help with any casting you may need to do: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/201837/order-by-gives-error-function-array-positiontext-character-varying-does-no

Comment: Hey Daniil, can I do same thing in slick for postgres?

Comment: Not really sure, probably worth asking separate question

Answer (score 64):

Each expression gets evaluated as a bool and treated as 0 for false and 1 for true and sorted appropriately. Even though this works, the logic is hard to follow (and thus maintain). What I use is a function that finds a value's index in an array.

```
ORDER BY idx(array['Nails','Bolts','Washers','Screws','Staples','Nuts'], s.type)
```

This is much easier to follow. Nails will be sorted first and nuts sorted last. You can see how to create the idx function in the Postgres snippets repository.
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_Index

Comment: should be `array_position`

Comment: @EbenGeer only on 9.5 and above

Comment: So with 9.5+ one can simply use `array_position` here? @DarkMukke I'd add this to your answer.

Answer (score 12):

with array_position, it needs to have the same type that you're querying against.

e.g:

```
select array_position(array['foo'::char,'bar','baz'::char], 'bar');
select array_position(array['foo'::char,'bar','baz'::char], 'baz'::char);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is to **sort by a given list of values**.

Since Postgres 9.4, a clean solution is to `LEFT JOIN` to an unnested array [**`WITH ORDINALITY`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) and `ORDER BY` the resulting ordinality number:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM   ...
LEFT   JOIN unnest ('{Nails,Bolts,Washers,Screws,Staples,Nuts}'::text[]) WITH ORDINALITY sort(type, ord) USING (type)
ORDER  BY sort.ord ...
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9uP5JtGz)

See:

- [ORDER BY the IN value list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list/35456954#35456954)