# SQLALchemy custom integer sort order

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table with a column of integers that represent the `type` of the row. These integers range from 1 - 5. How do I specify a custom sort order in SQLAlchemy, for example if I want the rows sorted in the following order `[4, 2, 3, 5, 1]`?

I'm aware of the [Enum](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html?#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) datatype, but that maps to a VARCHAR in the database backend and changing the schema is not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is my guess that you must already have some table which contains some information about the `type` or row. And if you do not, maybe you should have such a look-up table. In case this ordering is always the same, I would then add a column to this table to indicate the ordering, join on it and use it.

```
class TypeInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'typeinfo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sort_order = Column(Integer)

# assiming the database contains values like:
tis = [ TypeInfo(id=1, sort_order=50),
        TypeInfo(id=2, sort_order=20),
        TypeInfo(id=3, sort_order=30),
        TypeInfo(id=4, sort_order=10),
        TypeInfo(id=5, sort_order=40),
        ]

# your query might look like below:
q = session.query(SomeTable)
q = q.join(TypeInfo, SomeTable.type == TypeInfo.id).order_by(TypeInfo.sort_order)
```

In case when you cannot change the database, or the ordering might be different, you can solve this with the [`case`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) expression, although it might not be quick performer on large datasets:

```
_whens = {4: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 5: 4, 1: 5}
sort_order = case(value=SomeTable.type, whens=_whens)
q = session.query(SomeTable)
q = q.order_by(sort_order)
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, and while I'm not averse to creating a table that contains the sort order that does seem a little overkill to me. I personally wouldn't do that in SQL. Databases provide you with some neat [syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4088921/463782), like `ORDER BY idx(array[4, 2, 3, 5, 1], s.type)`. The case one is much closer to what I had in mind, but I'll keep an eye on the performance.

Comment: After some testing, the `case` expression works well and I don't notice any performance dips. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This does not solves the generic issue the tile represents. There are infinite integers so you cannot just create a look-up table to map all possible values.