# Sort a Django queryset based on the values in the choice field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have a model,

```
class Example(models.Model):
MY_CHOICES = (
    ("yes", _("Yes")),
    ("no", _("NO")),
    ("not_sure", _("Not sure")),
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_('Name'))
status = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=MY_CHOICES,default='yes')
```

I need to get the query set sorted in the get_queryset method, ie,

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = self.model._default_manager.get_queryset()
    order = ['yes', 'no', 'not_sure']
    qs = #CODE TO ORDER THE S HERE BASED ON order.
    return qs
```

*The return value i need is a QuerySet not a sorted list. 
*The qs need to be sorted based on the the status value according to the order 'yes', 'no', 'not_sure'.

Please Note: I need thr QS based on the object attribute value(ie, status value). In the order objects of status='yes' first followed by 'no' and 'not_sure'

Comment: make order a choice field and then sort according to the choice where first value will be 1,2,3 and so on like Order_choice=((1, yes), (2, no), (3, not_sure))

Comment: Thanx, But here I  need the db value the same 'yes', 'no' and 'not_sure'. This will store the numbers in db. :(

Comment: wouldn't the meta ordering be enough? `class Meta: ordering = ['status']`. Is there a specific reason for doing it in `get_queryset`?

Comment: If the `Meta` ordering does not work, you can always have 3 separate queries - one for `yes`, one for `no` and one for `not_sure`, and return the chained response in the `get_queryset`(The net effect is the same, as the queries are evaluated lazily)

Comment: @karthikr it's hard to tell what you mean but I don't think that will work, post some code

Comment: @Pynchila: Simply giving  ordering = ['status'] will not sort according to the values stored based on the choices. May be that will do a alphabetic ordering . Here in the quesryset I need in the order objects with status value  'yes' first followed by 'no', 'not_sure'.

Comment: OK thank you, it's clear now. I edited the question to explain it better

Comment: @Pynchila : Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given [this previous SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883575/custom-ordering-in-django)

and keeping your code, I'd say

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = self.model._default_manager.get_queryset()
    order = ['yes', 'no', 'not_sure']
    return sorted(qs, key=lambda x: order.index(x.status))
```

However, I'd rather have the DB do it instead.
Have a look at [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088532/custom-order-by-explanation) for a nice trick:

```
ORDER BY idx(array['yes', 'no', 'not_sure'], status)
```

Add the SQL fragment above to the query generated by django's ORM (or create one ex-novo) and perform a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/) with it:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = self.model._default_manager.get_queryset()
    newquery = qs.query+' ORDER BY idx(array'+order.__str__()+', status)'
    return self.model._default_manager.raw(newquery)
```

It should work, provided there is no `order by` clause already in the sql. I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution uses PostgreSQL-specific syntax. For other DBMSes like MySQL or SQLite, you would need a different syntax (e.g., `ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'yes', 'no', 'not_sure')` for MySQL). [See this SO answer for MySQL details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql) or [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303851/sqlite-and-custom-order-by) for SQLite.

Answer (score 17):

Update for newer Django versions (tested in v3.0.10), without custom SQL syntax, using [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value

class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.order_by( Case( 
                       When ( status="yes", then=Value(0) ),
                       When ( status="no", then=Value(1)  ),
                       default = Value(2)
                          )
                    )
```