# Ruby on Rails sort on priorities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following were my query to get list of countries along with cities:

```
@countries_cities = Product.joins(:user).where("country is not null and country <> ''").where("city is not null and city <> ''").where(:users => {:merchant_status => 1}).group(:country, :city).select("country,city").as_json
```

The output result were as follow:

```
Object[city:"Bangkok",country:"Thailand"],Object[city:"Phuket",country:"Thailand"],Object[city:"Malaysia",country:"Kuala Lumpur"],Object[city:"Malaysia",country:"Penang"],Object[city:"Shanghai",country:"China"],Object[city:"Beijing",country:"China"]

cchs = @countries_cities.group_by{|cc| cc["country"]}
@search_location_country = cchs
```

And the view is:

```
    <ul id="color-dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
      <% @search_location_country.each do |country, cities| %>
        <li class="input" style="background:#ECECEC; "><a href="#" style="font-weight: bold;"><%= country.upcase %></a></li>
                <%  cities.each do |city| %>
        <li class="input"><a href="#"><%= city["city"].titleize %></a></li>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

Now the Drop down result follow this pattern:

```
Thailand
  -Bangkok
  -Phuket
Malaysia
  -Kuala Lumpur
  -Penang
China
  -Beijing
  -Shanghai
```

How can I ensure that `Malaysia` will always place at the top of the drop down lists? Thanks!!

Comment: What SQL are you using? MySQL, Postgre?

Comment: @magni- I am using Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
@countries_cities = Product.joins(:user)
                           .where.not(country: [nil, ''])
                           .where(users: {merchant_status: 1})
                           .group(:country, :city)
                           .order("country!= 'Malaysia'")
                           .select(:country, :city)
                           .as_json
```

In Postgres, `false` is sorted before `true` (see this answer here: [Custom ORDER BY Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088532/custom-order-by-explanation))

Comment: ah, it works now!! how come set `country!= 'Malaysia'` makes `Malaysia` in top?

Comment: Check out the link for a more detailed explanation, but basically: rows that have `country` as `Malaysia` will have `country!= 'Malaysia'` evaluate to `false`, and those rows get sorted above rows where that evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 1):

You can customize you query like this:

```
@countries_cities = Product.joins(:user)
                           .where.not(country: [nil, ''])
                           .where(:users => {:merchant_status => 1})
                           .group(:country, :city)
                           .order("ORDER BY 
                                   CASE WHEN country = 'Malaysia' THEN 1
                                   ELSE 2
                                   END ASC")
                           .select(:country, :city)
                           .as_json
```

So we set the order of Malaysia = 2, and others = 1 to ensure the result with Malaysia will be on the top.

Comment: Nope, the result seem shows no changing in order of appearance

Comment: @d3bug3r: Hmm I just modify my answer, let try again!

Comment: Ok, it shows me some errors now `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ORDER"
LINE 1: ... "products"."country", "products"."city"  ORDER BY ORDER BY `

Comment: `: SELECT "products"."country", "products"."city" FROM "products" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "products"."user_id" WHERE (NOT (("products"."country" = '' OR "products"."country" IS NULL))) AND "users"."merchant_status" = $1 GROUP BY "products"."country", "products"."city"  ORDER BY ORDER BY 
                                   CASE WHEN country = 'Malaysia' THEN 1
                                   ELSE 2
                                   END ASC`