# How do I ORDER BY a JSON Array with its String Values?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a simple JSON array:

```
_bb jsonb =

[
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "FlashSale",
    "pos": "Bottom"
  },
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  }
]
```

What I want to achieve:

```
[
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "FlashSale",
    "pos": "Bottom"
  }
]
```

I tried doing

```
Select _bb  into _test  ORDER BY _bb->>'pos' ASC  ;
```

What I achieve is all the pos = "Top" be the first in the JSON and all the "Bottom" to be last. Is there a way to achieve this in Postgres?

Comment: I dont understand how `ORDER BY _bb->>'pos' ASC ` would help to change the array index - can you share the structure?.. also in your original jsonb, `_bb[1]` is equal to `_bb[3]` - right?.. so what you say you have achieved is what you want then - no?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088532/custom-order-by-explanation  This should do the trick. You just have to convert it to your case

Comment: @VaoTsun Yea its _bb[3], but i would like to change the sort orders by placing "Top" as the priority to be first before "bottom". I'm not really too sure on what the syntax is to achieve it.

Comment: alphabetically "bottom" is before "top" - are those two possible values or there can be more?..

Comment: @VaoTsun there can be more like "Middle"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with j(_bb) as (values('[
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "FlashSale",
    "pos": "Bottom"
  },
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  }
]'::jsonb))
, ord(o,v) as (values(1,'Top'),(2,'Bottom'))
, un as (select *,jsonb_array_elements(_bb) i from j)
select jsonb_agg(i order by o) from un
join ord on v=i->>'pos'
;
```

with result in:

```
[
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "Testing",
    "pos": "Top"
  },
  {
    "so": "1",
    "mdl": "FlashSale",
    "pos": "Bottom"
  }
]
```

needless to say you have to build order matrix for all values, eg:

```
, ord(o,v) as (values(1,'Top'),(2,'Middle'),(3,'Bottom'))
```

http://rextester.com/ZNDQ97753

Comment: Thank, but can you explain the first line " t=# with " im not too familiar with this syntax.

Comment: ah - `t=# ` is just a `psql` prompt, `with` is `CTE` syntax

Comment: noob question but, who do I test this out in a Query? I'm getting a syntax error "at or near t" when I do.

Comment: @Pickles I updated the answer, leaving query with no psql prompts or other decortions

Comment: and added link to live demo