# Order query results by items in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

How to let the query result be ordered by the exact order of passed items in the `WHERE` clause?

For example, using this query:

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM my_table
WHERE id in (1,3,5,2,4,6)
ORDER BY id
```

Result:

```
id | name
---------
1  |  a
2  |  b
3  |  c
4  |  d
5  |  e
6  |  f
```

What I expected:

```
id | name
---------
1  |  a
3  |  c
5  |  e
2  |  b
4  |  d
6  |  f
```

I noticed that there is a `FIELD()` function in MySQL. Is there an equivalent function in PostgreSQL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088532/custom-order-by-explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass an array and use [**`WITH ORDINALITY`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html). That's cleanest and fastest:

```sql
SELECT id, t.name
FROM   unnest ('{1,3,5,2,4,6}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY u(id, ord)
JOIN   my_table t USING (id)
ORDER  BY u.ord;
```

Assuming values in the passed array are distinct. Else, this solution preserves duplicates, while `IN` removes them. You'd have to define which behavior you want. But then the desired sort order is also ambiguous, which would make the question moot.

See:

- [ORDER BY the IN value list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list/35456954#35456954)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Answer (score 1):

@chris Kao, use Position in postgresql.

**Approach : 1**
SELECT id, name FROM my_table
WHERE id in (1,3,5,2,4,6)
order by position(id::text in '1,3,5,2,4,6')
output:

```
id|name|
--+----+
 1|a   |
 3|c   |
 5|e   |
 2|b   |
 4|d   |
 6|f   |
```

### **Aprroach : 2**

```
select id, name
from my_table mt
where id in (1,3,5,2,4,6)
order by array_position(array[1,3,5,2,4,6], mt.id);
```