# How to create a row number with specific order in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-number

Can anyone tell me how to get a row number like in the table below?

I have data:

- IDR (1 Month - 12 Month)
- USD (1 Month - 12 Month)
- SGD (1 Month - 12 Month)
- AUD (1 Month - 12 Month)

I want to have a row number exactly like the column "NO", where IDR goes first, then USD, SGD and AUD.

I tried using `order by Currency, left(month,2)`, but IDR doesn't go first.

| NO | Currency | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IDR | 1 Month |
| 2 | IDR | 3 Month |
| 3 | IDR | 4 Month |
| 4 | IDR | 5 Month |
| 5 | IDR | 6 Month |
| 6 | IDR | 12 Month |
| 7 | USD | 1 Month |
| 8 | USD | 3 Month |
| 9 | USD | 4 Month |
| 10 | USD | 5 Month |
| 11 | USD | 6 Month |
| 12 | USD | 12 Month |
| 13 | SGD | 1 Month |
| 14 | SGD | 3 Month |
| 15 | SGD | 4 Month |
| 16 | SGD | 5 Month |
| 17 | SGD | 6 Month |
| 18 | SGD | 12 Month |

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41386038/21018639

Answer (score 1):

Add a computed column to the query that uses a window function with an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT row_number()
          OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN currency = 'IDR' THEN 1
                              WHEN currency = 'USD' THEN 2
                              WHEN currency = 'SGD' THEN 3
                              WHEN currency = 'AUD' THEN 4
                         END,
                         split_part(month, ' ', 1)::integer),
       ...
FROM ...
```