# SQLite select query. Get row with array

Tags: ios, sqlite

I coder for iOS and I use SQLite for my data storage.

For now i have two tables in my database. This is **table_1** and **table_2** (it's easier for understanding)

About struct:

table_1 contain **id** field (int type) and **some_value** field (text type)

table_2 contain **id** field (int type) and **table_1_id** field (int type)

My question is next: how to select all row from table_1 via array table_1_id field table_2, and this is must SELECT with ORDER BY. I mean order by array.

For example:

if table_2 -> table_1_id contain value 5, 1, 10, 3, 15, 2

the result of output must be in this order.

For now my query is simple:

> SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id IN (5, 1, 10, 3, 15, 2)

but the select not return order for this query it return data order by 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 15.

I think I make relation between my table and make SELECT from table_2 uses ORDER BY, but I don't know how to do this correct.

Thanks in advance!

(Very important for me return this order - 5, 1, 10, 3, 15, 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find some result in stackoverflow

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/sql-order-by-the-in-value-list)

This is work for me:

> SELECT * FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."id" IN (1,3,2,4))  ORDER
>   BY  id=1 DESC, ID=3 DESC, id=2 DESC, ID=4 DESC

This is hard code but I create this query string programmatically in cycle and this work great.