# Find model records by ID in the order the array of IDs were given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a query to get the IDs of people in a particular order, say:
`ids = [1, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2]`

I then want to fetch those people by `Person.find(ids)`

But they are always fetched in numerical order, I know this by performing:

```
people = Person.find(ids).map(&:id)
 => [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]
```

How can I run this query so that the order is the same as the order of the ids array?

I made this task more difficult as I wanted to only perform the query to fetch people once, from the IDs given. So, performing multiple queries is out of the question.

I tried something like:

```
ids.each do |i|
  person = people.where('id = ?', i)
```

But I don't think this works.

Comment: Rails 7 solution here: https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/return-results-using-a-specific-order-in-rails

Comment: As of Rails 5, `find` returns the records in the same order as the ids provided ([docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find), [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20338)). The method `in_order_of` added in Rails 7 is only needed when using `where`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> *Editor's note:
>
> As of Rails 5, `find` returns the records in the same order as the provided IDs ([docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find)).*

Note on this code:

```
ids.each do |i|
  person = people.where('id = ?', i)
```

There are two issues with it:

First, the #each method returns the array it iterated on, so you'd just get the ids back.  What you want is a collect

Second, the where will return an Arel::Relation object, which in the end will evaluate as an array.  So you'd end up with an array of arrays.  You could fix two ways.

The first way would be by flattening:

```
ids.collect {|i| Person.where('id => ?', i) }.flatten
```

Even better version:

```
ids.collect {|i| Person.where(:id => i) }.flatten
```

A second way would by to simply do a find:

```
ids.collect {|i| Person.find(i) }
```

That's nice and simple

You'll find, however, that these all do a query for each iteration, so not very efficient.

I like Sergio's solution, but here's another I would have suggested:

```
people_by_id = Person.find(ids).index_by(&:id) # Gives you a hash indexed by ID
ids.collect {|id| people_by_id[id] }
```

I swear that I remember that ActiveRecord used to do this ID ordering for us.  Maybe it went away with Arel ;)

Comment: Just tried it in an old 2.3.8 project that I had and it turns out the find method doesn't order by the IDs automatically.  I must be getting old... ;)

Comment: Could you explain your altered suggestion a little? At what point can this then be used to iterate through the new people result in the correct order? Or did you comment because it wasn't working? Thank you for your input though, I found it very useful

Comment: I've tried your solution and it's benchmarking slightly faster than any other solution here, thanks!

Comment: I probably should have been clearer that you can take the second line and assign it or further iterate upon it.  I also probably should have started with my alternate solution, though I like starting from a bit of code and showing incremental changes until a more ideal solution is reached ;)

Comment: Yes I have to agree, it's always good to see contrast between alternatives that may work but are inferior!

Comment: index_by is great but watch out if you receive your array filled with ids by HTTP. Spend nearly an hour to realise that ["1", "2", "3"] != [1, 2, 3].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10150225/5515674 - please refer this solution

Answer (score 16):

As I see it, you can either map the IDs or sort the result. For the latter, there already are solutions, though I find them inefficient.

Mapping the IDs:

```
ids = [1, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2]
people_in_order = ids.map { |id| Person.find(id) }
```

Note that this will cause multiple queries to be executed, which is potentially inefficient.

Sorting the result:

```
ids = [1, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2]
id_indices = Hash[ids.map.with_index { |id,idx| [id,idx] }] # requires ruby 1.8.7+
people_in_order = Person.find(ids).sort_by { |person| id_indices[person.id] }
```

Or, expanding on Brian Underwoods answer:

```
ids = [1, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2]
indexed_people = Person.find(ids).index_by(&:id) # I didn't know this method, TIL :)
people_in_order = indexed_people.values_at(*ids)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, I tried your expanded answer which works - is this your preferred solution?

Comment: I haven't used index_by yet, but assuming it doesn't come with some inexplicably high performance penalty, then yes. It's quite concise in my opinion.

Comment: Actually it seemed to be one of the faster solutions here - but each solution was very closely timed, I didn't test your first solution though - I'd have to take your word on whether or not you feel it would be more efficient

Comment: As I say in the answer, the first solution is probably quite slow due to the overhead of using multiple queries. For small number of ids, that shouldn't matter. But my preference is on the third.

Comment: The last alternative works for me - Using Mongoid.

Answer (score 14):

If you have `ids` array then it is as simple as -

`Person.where(id: ids).sort_by {|p| ids.index(p.id) }`

OR

`persons = Hash[ Person.where(id: ids).map {|p| [p.id, p] }]
ids.map {|i| persons[i] }`

Answer (score 10):

With Rails 5, I've found that this approach works (with postgres, at least), even for scoped queries, useful for working with ElasticSearch:

```
Person.where(country: "France").find([3, 2, 1]).map(&:id)
=> [3, 2, 1]
```

Note that using `where` instead of `find` does not preserve the order.

```
Person.where(country: "France").where(id: [3, 2, 1]).map(&:id)
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Using find instead of where does the trick. Thank you a lot!

Comment: This works however, if the passed id is not present it will thrown an exception

Answer (score 8):

You can get users sorted by `id asc` from the database and then rearrange them in the application any way you want. Check this out:

```
ids = [1, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2]
users = ids.sort.map {|i| {id: i}} # Or User.find(ids) or another query

# users sorted by id asc (from the query)
users # => [{:id=>1}, {:id=>2}, {:id=>3}, {:id=>5}, {:id=>6}, {:id=>9}]

users.sort_by! {|u| ids.index u[:id]} 

# users sorted as you wanted
users # => [{:id=>1}, {:id=>3}, {:id=>5}, {:id=>9}, {:id=>6}, {:id=>2}]
```

The trick here is sorting the array by an artificial value: index of object's id in another array.

Comment: Just getting some sleep, will try this in the morning, thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer for me please? I can see that it works but, not sure how to use it with a result of people, with names, emails, etc.

Comment: Yeah, sure. The key line is the one with `sort_by!`. You provide a block that is then called with an instance of user. You extract an id from this object, find position of this id in your original id array, and this position will also be position of user object in the sorted array. User with id=5 will come third because `ids` array has 3 at third position.

Comment: So at what point would you do something like `users = User.find_all_by_id(ids)` to get the actual set to work with to be sorted?

Comment: Thanks Sergio, really learned a lot from this. I'm going to choose Brian's answer though, as I tested all the solutions and his benchmarks the fastest (although only ever so slightly, and all were very close). What do you think?

Comment: No problem. Pick the best answer :)

Comment: best solution :)

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to get entries by given an array of ids. If you are working on Rails 4, dynamic method are deprecated, you need to look at the Rails 4 specific solution below.

**Solution one:**

```
Person.find([1,2,3,4])
```

This will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if no record exists

**Solution two [Rails 3 only]:**

```
Person.find_all_by_id([1,2,3,4])
```

This will not cause exception, simply return empty array if no record matches your query.

Based on your requirement choosing the method you would like to use above, then sorting them by given `ids`

```
ids = [1,2,3,4]
people = Person.find_all_by_id(ids)
# alternatively: people = Person.find(ids)
ordered_people = ids.collect {|id| people.detect {|x| x.id == id}}
```

**Solution [Rails 4 only]:**

I think Rails 4 offers a better solution.

```
# without eager loading
Person.where(id: [1,2,3,4]).order('id DESC')

# with eager loading.
# Note that you can not call deprecated `all`
Person.where(id: [1,2,3,4]).order('id DESC').load
```

Comment: The Rails 4 solution doesn't answer the question.  You are ordering by the numerical value of the id.  That is how Rails does it by default.

Comment: The question asked how to order ids in the way they were passed in... not by a default ASC or DESC

Answer (score 8):

I here summarise the solutions, plus adding recent (9.4+) PostgreSQL-specific solution. The following is based on Rails 6.1 and PostgreSQL 12. Though I mention solutions for earlier versions of Rails and PostgreSQL, I haven't actually tested them with earlier versions.

For reference, this [question "ORDER BY the IN value list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list) gives various ways of sorting/ordering with the database.

Here, I assume the model is guaranteed to have all the records specified by the Array of IDs, `ids`. Otherwise, an exception like `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` may be raised (or may not, depending on the way).

### What does NOT work

```rb
Person.where(id: ids)
```

The order of the returned Relation is either arbitrary or that of the numerical values of the primary IDs; whichever, it usually does not agree with that of `ids`.

### Simple solution to get an Array

(Rails 5+ only(?))

```rb
Person.find ids
```

which returns a Ruby Array of Person models in the order of the given `ids`.

A downside is you cannot further modify the result with SQL.

In Rails 3, the following is the way apparently, though this may not work (certainly does not in Rails 6) in the other versions of Rails.

```rb
Person.find_all_by_id ids
```

#### Pure Ruby solution to get an Array

Two ways. Either works regardless of Rails versions (I think).

```rb
Person.where(id: ids).sort_by{|i| ids.index(i.id)}
Person.where(id: ids).index_by(&:id).values_at(*ids)
```

which returns a Ruby Array of Person models in the order of the given `ids`.

### DB-level solution to get a Relation

All of the following return `Person::ActiveRecord_Relation`, to which you can apply more filters if you like.

In the following solutions, all records are preserved, including those whose IDs are not included in the given array `ids`. You can filter them out any time by adding `where(id: ids)` (this sort of flexibility is a beauty of `ActiveRecord_Relation`).

#### For any Database

Based on [user3033467's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61267426/3577922) but updated to work with Rails 6 (which has disabled some features with `order()` due to a security concern; see "[Updates for SQL Injection in Rails 6.1](https://dev.to/presidentbeef/updates-for-sql-injection-in-rails-6-1-1cbo)" by Justin for the background).

```rb
order_query = <<-SQL
  CASE musics.id 
    #{ids.map.with_index { |id, index| "WHEN #{id} THEN #{index}" } .join(' ')}
    ELSE #{ids.length}
  END
SQL

Person.order(Arel.sql(order_query))
```

#### For MySQL specific

From [Koen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38378457/1701) (I haven't tested it).

```rb
Person.order(Person.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ['FIELD(id, ?)', ids])).find(ids)
```

#### For PostgreSQL specific

##### PostgreSQL 9.4+

```rb
join_sql = "INNER JOIN unnest('{#{ids.join(',')}}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY t(id, ord) USING (id)"
Person.joins(join_sql).order("t.ord")
```

##### PostgreSQL 8.2+

Based on [Jerph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43236479/3577922), but `LEFT JOIN` is replaced with `INNER JOIN`:

```rb
val_ids = ids.map.with_index.map{|id, i| "(#{id}, #{i})"}.join(", ")
Person.joins("INNER JOIN (VALUES #{val_ids}) AS persons_id_order(id, ordering) ON persons.id = persons_id_order.id")
  .order("persons_id_order.ordering")
```

### To get lower-level objects

The following is solutions to get lower-level objects.
In a vast majority of cases, the solutions described above must be superior to these, but am putting there here for the sake of completeness (and record before I found better solutions)…

In the following solutions, the records that do not match IDs in `ids` are filtered out, unlike the solutions described in the previous section (where all records can be chosen to be preserved).

#### To get an ActiveRecord::Result

This is a solution to get `ActiveRecord::Result` with PostgreSQL 9.4+.

`ActiveRecord::Result` is similar to an Array of Hash.

```rb
str_sql = "select persons.* from persons INNER JOIN unnest('{#{ids.join(',')}}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY t(id, ord) USING (id) ORDER BY t.ord;"
Person.connection.select_all(str_sql)
```

`Person.connection.exec_query` returns the same (alias?).

#### To get a PG::Result

This is a solution to get `PG::Result` with PostgreSQL 9.4+.  Very similar to above, but replace `exec_query` with `execute` (the first line is identical to the solution above):

```rb
str_sql = "select persons.* from persons INNER JOIN unnest('{#{ids.join(',')}}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY t(id, ord) USING (id) ORDER BY t.ord;"
Person.connection.execute(str_sql)
```

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but the sorting can be done by ordering using the SQL `FIELD` function. *(Only tested this with MySQL.)*

So in this case something like this should work:

```
Person.order(Person.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ['FIELD(id, ?)', ids])).find(ids)
```

Which results in the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM people
  WHERE id IN (1, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2)
  ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Most of the other solutions don't allow you to further filter the resulting query, which is why I like [Koen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38378457/1701).

Similar to that answer but for Postgres, I add this function to my ApplicationRecord (Rails 5+) or to any model (Rails 4):

```
def self.order_by_id_list(id_list)
  values_clause = id_list.each_with_index.map{|id, i| "(#{id}, #{i})"}.join(", ")
  joins("LEFT JOIN (VALUES #{ values_clause }) AS #{ self.table_name}_id_order(id, ordering) ON #{ self.table_name }.id = #{ self.table_name }_id_order.id")
    .order("#{ self.table_name }_id_order.ordering")
end
```

The query solution is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list).

Comment: Great answer! This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! :)

Comment: You'll need to replace `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN` to match the original query so that this method works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

This is most efficiently handled in SQL via ActiveRecord and not in Ruby.

```
ids = [3,1,6,7,12,2]
Post.where(id: ids).order("FIELD(id, #{ids.join(',')})")
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution costs less than joining on values:

```ruby
order_query = <<-SQL
  CASE persons.id 
    #{ids.map.with_index { |id, index| "WHEN #{id} THEN #{index}" } .join(' ')}
    ELSE #{ids.length}
  END
SQL
Person.where(id: ids).order(order_query)
```

Comment: +1 for this should *potentially* work regardless of the database. But I find a modification with `Arel()` is essential for Rails 6.1 as `order(Arel.sql(order_query))`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers recommending the FIELD method on Rails6 but was encountering errors. However, I discovered that all one has to do is wrap the sql in `Arel.sql()`.

```
# Make sure it's a known-safe values.
user_ids = [3, 2, 1]
# Before 
users = User.where(id: user_ids).order("FIELD(id, 2, 3, 1)")
# With warning.

# After 
users = User.where(id: user_ids).order(Arel.sql("FIELD(id, 2, 3, 1)"))
# No warning
```

[1] https://medium.com/@mitsun.chieh/activerecord-relation-with-raw-sql-argument-returns-a-warning-exception-raising-8999f1b9898a

Answer (score 0):

Use find:

```
Thing.find([4, 2, 6])
```

For Rails 7:

```
Thing.where(id: [4, 2, 6]).in_order_of(:id, [4, 2, 6])
```

See https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/return-results-using-a-specific-order-in-rails

Answer (score -1):

To get the IDs of people in a particular order, say: `ids = [1, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2]`

In older version of rails, find and where fetch data in numerical order, but rails 5 fetch data in the same order in which you query it

> Note: find preserve the order and where don't preserve it

```
Person.find(ids).map(&:id)
=> [1, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2]

Person.where(id: ids).map(&:id)
=> [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]
```