# How can I avoid the Warning "firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!" when using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, ejb-3.0

I'm getting a warning in the Server log **"firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!"**. However everything working fine. But I don't want this warning.

### My code is

```java
public employee find(int id) {
    return (employee) getEntityManager().createQuery(QUERY).setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
}
```

### My query is

```java
QUERY = "from employee as emp left join fetch emp.salary left join fetch emp.department where emp.id = :id"
```

Comment: Please add code where you build and execute query.

Comment: JMelnik, Please see my edited question with Code and query.

Comment: Query also, where you set your maxResult parameters.

Comment: This is the code and query in my application. I don't set maxResult manually.

Comment: This means that Hibernate is fetching everything and then **trying to apply the first/max result restrictions in memory**. This may seem undesirable to you. Here's what the JPA spec has to say about this kind of interaction: "The effect of applying `setMaxResults` or `setFirstResult` to a query involving fetch joins over collections is undefined. ([JPA "Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0, Final Release"](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/), Kapitel 3.6.1 Query Interface)"

Comment: @Prince how you finally solve the problem? mind sharing with me, because I have the exact isisue

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Reason for this warning is that when fetch join is used, order in result sets is defined only by ID of selected entity (and not by join fetched).

If this sorting in memory is causing problems, do not use firsResult/maxResults with JOIN FETCH.

Answer (score 49):

Although you are getting valid results, the SQL query fetches all data and it's not as efficient as it should.

So, you have two options.

### Fixing the issue with two SQL queries that can fetch entities in read-write mode

The easiest way to fix this issue is to execute two queries:

. The first query will fetch the root entity identifiers matching the provided filtering criteria.
. The second query will use the previously extracted root entity identifiers to fetch the parent and the child entities.

This approach is very easy to implement and looks as follows:

```
List<Long> postIds = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select p.id " +
    "from Post p " +
    "where p.title like :titlePattern " +
    "order by p.createdOn", Long.class)
.setParameter(
    "titlePattern",
    "High-Performance Java Persistence %"
)
.setMaxResults(5)
.getResultList();
 
List<Post> posts = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select distinct p " +
    "from Post p " +
    "left join fetch p.comments " +
    "where p.id in (:postIds) "  +
    "order by p.createdOn", Post.class)
.setParameter("postIds", postIds)
.setHint(
    "hibernate.query.passDistinctThrough", 
    false
)
.getResultList();
```

### Fixing the issue with one SQL query that can only fetch entities in read-only mode

The second approach is to use SDENSE_RANK over the result set of parent and child entities that match our filtering criteria and restrict the output for the first N post entries only.

The SQL query can look as follows:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "PostWithCommentByRank",
    query =
        "SELECT * " +
        "FROM (   " +
        "    SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY \"p.created_on\", \"p.id\") rank " +
        "    FROM (   " +
        "        SELECT p.id AS \"p.id\", " +
        "               p.created_on AS \"p.created_on\", " +
        "               p.title AS \"p.title\", " +
        "               pc.id as \"pc.id\", " +
        "               pc.created_on AS \"pc.created_on\", " +
        "               pc.review AS \"pc.review\", " +
        "               pc.post_id AS \"pc.post_id\" " +
        "        FROM post p  " +
        "        LEFT JOIN post_comment pc ON p.id = pc.post_id " +
        "        WHERE p.title LIKE :titlePattern " +
        "        ORDER BY p.created_on " +
        "    ) p_pc " +
        ") p_pc_r " +
        "WHERE p_pc_r.rank <= :rank ",
    resultSetMapping = "PostWithCommentByRankMapping"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "PostWithCommentByRankMapping",
    entities = {
        @EntityResult(
            entityClass = Post.class,
            fields = {
                @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "p.id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "createdOn", column = "p.created_on"),
                @FieldResult(name = "title", column = "p.title"),
            }
        ),
        @EntityResult(
            entityClass = PostComment.class,
            fields = {
                @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "pc.id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "createdOn", column = "pc.created_on"),
                @FieldResult(name = "review", column = "pc.review"),
                @FieldResult(name = "post", column = "pc.post_id"),
            }
        )
    }
)
```

The `@NamedNativeQuery` fetches all Post entities matching the provided title along with their associated `PostComment` child entities. The `DENSE_RANK` Window Function is used to assign the rank for each Post and `PostComment` joined record so that we can later filter just the amount of Post records we are interested in fetching.

The `SqlResultSetMapping` provides the mapping between the SQL-level column aliases and the JPA entity properties that need to be populated.

Now, we can execute the `PostWithCommentByRank` `@NamedNativeQuery` like this:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager
.createNamedQuery("PostWithCommentByRank")
.setParameter(
    "titlePattern",
    "High-Performance Java Persistence %"
)
.setParameter(
    "rank",
    5
)
.unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
.setResultTransformer(
    new DistinctPostResultTransformer(entityManager)
)
.getResultList();
```

Now, by default, a native SQL query like the `PostWithCommentByRank` one would fetch the Post and the `PostComment` in the same JDBC row, so we will end up with an `Object[]` containing both entities.

However, we want to transform the tabular `Object[]` array into a tree of parent-child entities, and for this reason, we need to use the Hibernate [`ResultTransformer`](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/).

The `DistinctPostResultTransformer` looks as follows:

```
public class DistinctPostResultTransformer
        extends BasicTransformerAdapter {
 
    private final EntityManager entityManager;
 
    public DistinctPostResultTransformer(
            EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
 
    @Override
    public List transformList(
            List list) {
             
        Map<Serializable, Identifiable> identifiableMap =
            new LinkedHashMap<>(list.size());
             
        for (Object entityArray : list) {
            if (Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(entityArray.getClass())) {
                Post post = null;
                PostComment comment = null;
 
                Object[] tuples = (Object[]) entityArray;
 
                for (Object tuple : tuples) {
                    if(tuple instanceof Identifiable) {
                        entityManager.detach(tuple);
 
                        if (tuple instanceof Post) {
                            post = (Post) tuple;
                        }
                        else if (tuple instanceof PostComment) {
                            comment = (PostComment) tuple;
                        }
                        else {
                            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                                "Tuple " + tuple.getClass() + " is not supported!"
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
 
                if (post != null) {
                    if (!identifiableMap.containsKey(post.getId())) {
                        identifiableMap.put(post.getId(), post);
                        post.setComments(new ArrayList<>());
                    }
                    if (comment != null) {
                        post.addComment(comment);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(identifiableMap.values());
    }
}
```

The [`DistinctPostResultTransformer`](https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/) must detach the entities being fetched because we are overwriting the child collection and we don’t want that to be propagated as an entity state transition:

```
post.setComments(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Isn't the sorting missing in second query (the one loading the "Posts")? Can we rely on that the database returns the Posts in the same order the ids are given? I think one can simply add `order by p.createdOn` to the second query as well...

Comment: The posts are already fetched in the right order provided by the first query, and you can use that `List` reference to retain the order. The second query just replaces the uninitialized child association with a non-proxy `List`.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the database? In Postgres I had to add the ORDER BY clause to the second query as well. Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/866465/716834 seems to confirm this...

Comment: Does anyone know how to make this work with a custom predicate? I am trying to build a search endpoint. But it seems as though I can't combine custom predicate, page request, and native SQL all at once...

Answer (score 21):

To avoid this WARNING you have to change the call `getSingleResult` to 
`getResultList().get(0)`

Comment: Though the votes might already indicate this: this is indeed true. Even for queries that do not use any pagination such as `setFirstResult(offset)` or `setMaxResults(limit)`, Hibernate might still complain about that when using `getSingleResult`. (I assume Hibernate is limiting internally.)

Comment: A notable difference is that this will not throw an exception when a query that you expected to return 1 result actually returned multiple results. I'd add some kind of assertion.

Comment: I'm getting this warning with JOIN FETCH despite already using getResultList(). So this can't be the *only* potential solution to this problem.

Answer (score 19):

This warning tells you Hibernate is performing in memory java pagination. This can cause high JVM memory consumption.
Since a developer can miss this warning, I contributed to Hibernate by adding a flag allowing to throw an exception instead of logging the warning (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9965).

The flag is **hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch**.

I recommend everyone to enable it.

The flag is defined in **org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings** :

```
    /**
     * Raises an exception when in-memory pagination over collection fetch is about to be performed.
     * Disabled by default. Set to true to enable.
     *
     * @since 5.2.13
     */
    String FAIL_ON_PAGINATION_OVER_COLLECTION_FETCH = "hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch";
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you will get cartesian product doing JOIN. The offset will cut your recordset without looking if you are still on same root identity class

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, you should generally avoid using "JOIN FETCH" and firstResult/maxResults together.
If your query requires it, you can use `.stream()` to eliminate warning and avoid potential OOM exception.

```java
try (Stream<ENTITY> stream = em.createQuery(QUERY).stream()) {
    ENTITY first = stream.findFirst().orElse(null); // equivalents .getSingleResult()
}
```

// `Stream` returned is an IO stream that needs to be closed manually.

Comment: Did you know stream just loads it all into memory anyway and streams it out?

Comment: Load all data is not the definition of stream but implementation would be vendor-specific. In that case, it would be great if you can elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the emp has many departments which is a One to Many relationship. Hibernate will fetch many rows for this query with fetched department records. So the order of result set can not be decided until it has really fetch the results to the memory. So the pagination will be done in memory.

If you do not want to fetch the departments with emp, but still want to do some query based on the department, you can achieve the result with out warning (without doing ordering in the memory). For that simply you have to remove the "fetch" clause. So something like as follows:

QUERY = "from employee as emp left join emp.salary sal left join emp.department dep where emp.id = :id and dep.name = 'testing' and sal.salary > 5000 "