# QueryDsl with pagination

Tags: java, spring, jpa, querydsl

I have QueryDsl query with Spring jpa written like:

```
JPAQuery<FooEntity> query = getQuerydsl()
        .<FooEntity>createQuery()
        .from(foo)
        .leftJoin(foo.bar, bar).fetchJoin()
        .leftJoin(...).fetchJoin()
        .where(predicate)
        .distinct();
    return new PageImpl<>(getQuerydsl().applyPagination(pageable, query).fetch(), pageable,
        query.fetchCount());
```

FetchJoin is used because data from joined tables is needed. The strange thing is that some of these queries have correct SQL ending on `limit ?,?`. It means pagination is applied inside the database.

But if the mapping is done via `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "...")` and not `@JoinColumn()`, then all data is loaded into memory and I see the warning:

```
HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
```

How to avoid loading all data into memory in this case?

Comment: Please give a look in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431670/how-can-i-avoid-the-warning-firstresult-maxresults-specified-with-collection-fe) . It seems that is more a jpa related issue than query dsl's.