# How can I solve memory error in Hibernate Jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I downloaded a Spring Boot application from GitHub. Initially it was working fine and I have tested. Everything was working fine. Now I am getting the below warning while loading Landing page of application.

2020-11-29 00:07:02.511  WARN 6084 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] o.h.h.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl   : HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!

I did not change anything in the application/database. I am not understanding, What could be the problem?

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Try to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431670/how-can-i-avoid-the-warning-firstresult-maxresults-specified-with-collection-fe)

Comment: Problem is same but in my case initially my application was running without any exception or warning, but now it's not working even I did not change anything

Comment: If your application now isn't working, then that **warning** you quoted probably is not the problem.

Comment: Did you try tips from articke provided here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://tech.asimio.net/2021/05/19/Fixing-Hibernate-HHH000104-firstResult-maxResults-warning-using-Spring-Data-JPA.html&ved=2ahUKEwjDrd3QlfP0AhVFSvEDHT_nBUwQFnoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1zpaEtHkxSzGMDcbRN4y_H