# Pageable with @Query on Spring Data JPA findAll(specification, pageable)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm having issues with findAll method which I am overriding from JpaSpecificationExecutor

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
@Query(value = "select distinct user from User user left join fetch user.shopList shopList",
            countQuery = "select count(distinct user) from User user")
    Page<User> findAll(Specification specification, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I get "firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch. In memory pagination was about to be applied" error.
It's like it's not using Pageable object at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid the Warning "firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!" when using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431670/how-can-i-avoid-the-warning-firstresult-maxresults-specified-with-collection-fe)