# Hibernate/JPA Named Query IS NOT generating ROWNUM in Oracle

Tags: hibernate, jpa, pagination, rownum

My Database is Oracle. I Have a simple named query, and I use JPA to try to paginate it:

```
query.setFirstResult(firstResult);
query.setMaxResults(maxResult);
```

The **generated query does not generates the pagination (rownum**).The Sql in the log does not have any sign of rownum or any pagination.

The Dialect is correct:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
```

The Driver I'm using:

```
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
<version>11.2.0.3</version>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Does your query use collection joins? If so, Hibernate might be doing the paging in memory. Look for 'firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!' in the logs

Comment: thats it, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431670/how-can-i-avoid-the-warning-firstresult-maxresults-specified-with-collection-fe