# How to retain the order of results while using a IN Clause in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

I need to get a set of results using the `IN` clause, but the default ordering is done and the results are returned. Is there a way to maintain the order of the in clause in db2 ?

`ORDER BY FILED` would be a solution in MySQL but is there an equivalent in DB2 ?

Comment: yes: use an ORDER BY !

Comment: Thanks for the reply.ORDER BY? The list is dynamic in every case. I invoke it via a prepared statement.

Can you give me an example?

Comment: You mean in the code you haven't posted?

Comment: SELECT POST_ID,POST_TITLE FROM BLOG_POST WHERE POST_ID IN (68,76,72,73);

This is the requirement, I need to get the results in the same order

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to do this:

```
select foo from table where bar in (3, 1, 2);
```

and order by which item bar matched.  i.e. `bar = 3` comes first, followed by 1, then 2.

I don't think there is a built-in way to do what you want in DB2.

However, take a look at [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155930/how-do-i-preserve-the-order-of-a-sql-query-using-the-in-command), which discusses workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want results in a particular order, ORDER BY is how to do it. SQL does not guarantee an order unless you use ORDER BY. There is no relationship whatsoever between a sort order of a result set and the way you choose to list items in any IN() clause. An IN() clause has nothing to do with it.

Note that a specific sort order may be obtained at any time without ORDER BY purely by luck. However, it is not guaranteed. If rows change over time, a different sort order might show up without warning.

This is a SQL behavior, not DB2. DB2 simply works for this behavior the way SQL is intended to work.