# Sort a rails query based on array order

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to sort an ActiveRecord query based on the values in an array. Something like:

```
@fruits=Fruit.where(seeds: true)._________________________
```

Say I wanted to sort the results by color using the array `['Red','Blue','Yellow']`

I see where SQL supports the use of a case statement for custom ordering, does Rails have something that utilizes this?

Comment: I doubt it, you'll probably have to use a bit of custom SQL with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9475755/2076787 or MySQL's `FIELD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, you can use `FIELD`. It would look like:

```
@fruit = Fruit.where(seeds: true).order("FIELD(color, 'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow')")
```

Comment: (Assuming the color column is called `color`)