# In clauses problems

Tags: sql-server

i have been execute simple 3 sql query

```
SELECT * FROM Table where rowid in(1,2,3)
SELECT * FROM Table where rowid in(2,1,3)
SELECT * FROM Table where rowid in(3,2,1)
```

all Query return same result. means execute Query first in(1,2,3) so get result like

1) first record which rowid is 1

2) second record which rowid is 2

3) third record which rowid is 3

same like other Query.

If I'm calling second and third Query the result are same like first Query but I want get result by rowid calling sequence.

Comment: Of course they're all the same result - the sets aren't ordered, the queries are all identical

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/sql-order-by-the-in-value-list  (the accepted answer is ANSI standard SQL)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM Table where rowid in(1,2,3) ORDER BY rowid ASC
SELECT * FROM Table where rowid in(2,1,3) ORDER BY 
(
  CASE rowid 
    WHEN 2 
    THEN 1 
    WHEN 1 
    THEN 2 
    WHEN 3 
    THEN 3 
  END
)
SELECT * FROM Table where rowid in(3,2,1) ORDER BY rowid DESC
```

Comment: the rowid will not static it become more then 3 or it could be different.

Answer (score 0):

When the server executes the query it basically for each row, determines whether it satisfies the `where` clause - so the `where` clause only determines **if** the row is in the result set, and not it's place.

Since the tables is actually a set, there is no intrinsic ordering of the rows (any order is supposed to be considered accidental), if you need ordered data you need to `order` it explicitly `by` the fields you want to sort, i.e.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE rowid in(2, 1, 3)
ORDER BY rowid
```

Comment: it doesn't sort the rows?