# Laravel - Get specific rows first from db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I want to "fix" the first three results in my array, that I get from my be so here is my example:

```
$ids = explode(',', '2,3,1');

$result = Items::whereIn('id', $ids)
                    ->where('active', '1')
                    ->get();
```

So I want this to return an array where the id 2 is the first, then 2, then 1. The order of the id's will be determent different each time, so I can't do something like order by id etc.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Raw for FIELD

```
$result = Items::whereIn('id', $ids)
                    ->where('active', '1')
                    ->orderByRaw('FIELD(id,$ids)')
                    ->get();
```