# Expressing JOIN with dynamic VALUES in @Query

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

The following query was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/867578/474034). The only difference is that I need to match against a list of Enumeration values that contain possible attributes that I must filter. In addition the list of values will be dynamically set and may contain between 1 and 10 enumeration values.

```
select c.*
from comments c
join (
  values
    ("FOO",1),
    ("BAR",2),
    ("BAZ",3),
) as x (attribute, ordering) on c.attribute = x.attribute
order by x.ordering
```

How can I express this nested `JOIN` and the `VALUE` pairs in a Spring `@Query` method of a Spring Data repository? What other options are there to express this query in a Spring application?

I am open for solutions using both Hibernate, JPA or Spring Data (JPA).

**Update**
I use `Comment` to demonstrate the issue, in practice I have a more complex entity. For the purpose of this question lets assume `Comment` is defined like this:

```
@Entity
class Comment {

   @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
   String text;
   @Enumerated (value = EnumType.STRING)
   AttributeEnum attribute; //enum values: FOO, BAR, BAZ
}
```

Now, I want to select all comments where attribute is either `'BAR'` or `'BAZ'` and I want to specify at runtime that `'BAZ'` comments should be ordered before `'BAR'` comments.

I am looking to implement a function which behaves similar to the following:

```
Page<Comment> findCommentsByAttributeIn(List<AttributeEnum> attributes,
                                        Pageable pageable);
```

with the added constraint, that the sorting matches the order of attributes in the list. So if `BAZ` comes before `BAR` in the list it will be sorted before `BAR`.

Comment: Could you show a code of Comment entity? And what is the main aim of your issue, get comments with sorted nested attributes?

Comment: "I want to specify at runtime that 'BAZ' comments should be ordered before 'BAR' comments" - as I understand, you are meaning ascending or descending ordering by `attribute`, like `findByAttributeInOrderByAttributeDesc` for example? Or you need an arbitrary order?

Comment: I realized what you mean... ))

Comment: What is the problem? Doesn't the query work? If so, what happens? Or don't you know where to put it? The title seems to suggest that you know that already?

Comment: The problem is that my `attributes` list is dynamic, I might be getting three enum values or five. So I need to create the join table dynamically at run time. It seems that @Query only supports static queries, so I need some kind of alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the following solution:

First create predefine table with sorting order sets (all you need):

sorting_sets

```
attribute | ordering | set
------------------------------
FOO       |     1    |  1
BAR       |     2    |  1
BAZ       |     3    |  1
FOO       |     3    |  2
BAR       |     2    |  2
BAZ       |     1    |  2
```

Then you can use the following query:

```
@Query(value = "select c.* from comments c join sorting_sets ss on ss.attribute = c.attribute and ss.set = ?1 order by ss.ordering", nativeQuery = true)
List<Comment> getCommentsBySortingSet(int sortingSet);
```

to get sorting order related to the given set.