# Flask and sqlalchemy: order query with value in list in base query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using Flask, sqlalchemy with postgres:

I have some code in Flask to query result in my models.

the first one can be:

```
campaignpage =  campaignpages.filter_by(folder=folder)
```

And i have a list of IDs like:

```
cps_selected = [1,2,3,4,5,9,10]
```

i created `cps_selecteds = [1,2,3,4,5,9,10, ...]`

I have tried to get all campaigns from cps_selected and campaignpage.

```
campaignpage = DBInboundCampaign.query.filter(DBInboundCampaign.id.in_(cps_selecteds))
```

and make paginate:

```
campaignpage = campaignpage.paginate(page, per_page=50)
```

But the order of the campaign is changed, and i want to order cps_selected campaigns first in my paginate

I have tried several thread in google but no luck.

Comment: Since your `cps_selecteds` is ordered, could you not just add `campaignpage.order_by(DBInboundCampaign.id)`? Of course if the IDs are not always ordered, it is a different story.

Comment: You might find solutions for the latter case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list

Comment: cps_selecteds is a list and is not ordered.