# Postgresql-9.6 SELECT * FROM table WHERE value IN array preserve his order

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by, postgresql-9.6

I am running the following query again my postgresql-9.6.5 database. I want to receive the result preserving the order of the array ('dpmYLNG', 'upXGxTB', 'tNV4rd5', '8o6Zejg').

```sql
SELECT taxi.id as taxi_id
FROM taxi
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.vehicle v ON (v.id = taxi.vehicle_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.vehicle_description vd ON (v.id = vd.vehicle_id)
WHERE
vd.special_need_vehicle != true
AND vd.type_ != 'mpv'
AND taxi.id IN ('dpmYLNG', 'upXGxTB', 'tNV4rd5', '8o6Zejg');
```

I found references questions: [ORDER BY the IN value list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list), but I don't think `ORDER BY POSITION` work for string.

My second approach would be to use a function: `WITH ORDINALITY`, but I am not really familiar with function in postgresql. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html

I have try using the `ORDER BY POSITION` keyword with not success.

```sql
SELECT taxi.id as taxi_id
FROM taxi
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.vehicle v ON (v.id = taxi.vehicle_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.vehicle_description vd ON (v.id = vd.vehicle_id)
WHERE
vd.special_need_vehicle != true
AND vd.type_ != 'mpv'
AND taxi.id IN ('dpmYLNG', 'upXGxTB', 'tNV4rd5', '8o6Zejg')
ORDER BY POSITION(id::text IN "('tNV4rd5', '8o6Zejg')");
```

I recieve the following error message:

```sql
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "('tNV4rd5', '8o6Zejg')" does not exist Position: 372.
```

I want to receive the value: 'tNV4rd5', but I am receiving the value: '8o6Zejg'.

I should not be the first person having this problem, **Thank for the help**.

Comment: Why not create a table with your `taxi_ids` and a `priority` column? Then `JOIN` with that and `ORDER BY taxi_id.priority`? In that way, your list is scalable as more IDs are added.

Comment: The condition `vd.special_need_vehicle != true` defeats the outer join, converting it to an inner join.