# in postgresql how can I order by an arbitrary list?

Tags: postgresql

I want to supply a list of names like: 'car','red'.

I have 2 tables:

```
A
id
b_id

B
id
name
```

I want to be able to select record and order them by a list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a  
JOIN b ON b.id = a.b_id 
ORDER BY b.name IN ('car','red') 
LIMIT 5
```

If the names are not in the list, then they appear after the items in the list, they do not get excluded.

I tried the above query, but it just gives me random items.
The list is arbitrary and I must reference them by name. How can I do this when I only have that list.

Comment: Please show us some data and the expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORDER BY the IN value list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list)

Comment: its close, but the problem is I have to generate the join data with code, so it different