# Preserve order of results with WHERE IN with jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

The issue has already been described in detail in [ORDER BY the IN value list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list),

but to repeat: I want to select items with ids 1,3,2,4 in that specific order.

My jOOQ snippet:

```
var results = create.select().from(ITEM).where(ITEM.ID.in(1,3,2,4)).fetchInto(Item.class);
```

The resulting `results` list will have items in order of 1,2,3,4.
How can I preserve the order of the items with jOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Field.sortAsc()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#sortAsc(T...)) for this:

```java
create.select()
      .from(ITEM)
      .where(ITEM.ID.in(1, 3, 2, 4))
      .orderBy(ITEM.ID.sortAsc(1, 3, 2, 4))
      .fetchInto(Item.class);
```

Or, of course, to avoid repeating the list, use a local variable:

```java
Integer[] ids = { 1, 3, 2, 4 };
create.select()
      .from(ITEM)
      .where(ITEM.ID.in(ids))
      .orderBy(ITEM.ID.sortAsc(ids))
      .fetchInto(Item.class);
```

[See also this article about sort indirection here](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/05/07/how-to-implement-sort-indirection-in-sql/).