# Selecting by ids with the precalculated order

Tags: postgresql

Here's the raw query I feed to the ORM I'm using:

```
SELECT
    "fightEventId"
FROM
    ${EDBTableNames.LOCATION_TIME_SLOT} AS lts
WHERE
    "fightId" IN (
        SELECT
            f.id
        FROM
            ${EDBTableNames.FIGHTS} AS f
        WHERE
            f.status = '${EFightStatus.CONFIRMED}'
    )
    AND "fightEventId" IN (
        SELECT
            fe.id
        FROM
            ${EDBTableNames.FIGHT_EVENTS} AS fe
        WHERE
            ${status.includes(EFightEventStatus.ONGOING)}
            AND (
                NOW() at time zone 'utc' >= fe.from AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' <= fe.to
            )
            OR ${status.includes(EFightEventStatus.UPCOMING)} AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' <= fe.to
            OR ${status.includes(EFightEventStatus.FINISHED)} AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' > fe.to
        ORDER BY fe."from" ASC
    )
GROUP BY "fightEventId"
HAVING
    COUNT("fightId") > ${SHOW_WITH_NUMBER_OF_FIGHTS}
LIMIT ${limit}
OFFSET ${page * limit};
```

The problem with this query is that even though fight events are ordered by the "from" date: `ORDER BY fe."from" ASC`, this subquery order is not maintained in the whole query. I need it to be maintained.

What would be the right way to do this? By the "right way" I mean performance and clarity.

Here is a bunch of options, but I'm a little bit confused as to which one to go for.

[ORDER BY the IN value list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list)

P.S.

`SHOW_WITH_NUMBER_OF_FIGHTS` is an integer and as of now it's required to be equal to 4.

Comment: What if the query over `${EDBTableNames.FIGHT_EVENTS}` returns the same fe.id multiple times with different fe."from" ?

Comment: @jjanes As far as I understand, according to the business logic, this scenario must be impossible.

Comment: @jjanes any ideas how to do that?

Comment: I'd like to rewrite it using `unnest `, but I can't figure out how...

Comment: You would want to rewrite it to use a `JOIN...ON ( "fightEventId"=fe.id)` rather than an IN list.  That will make other fields from the table available for use in a sort.  You might need to aggregate it with a dummy like `max(fe."from")`.  If the business logic guarantees there can only be one distinct value, then taking the max will just yield that value.